# PHP $_Session transfer across domain

Tags: php, server-side, subdomain

Yes, I know this has been asked a thousand times.. But, I've still been unable to find any specific fix that seems to work every time. I've tried many of the fixes people have suggested and I'm still having the same issue as before.

So, I run a server with a setup of multiple domains. They're all on the exact same server, and there is no transfer between servers here.

**carnal.ueteribus.com** <--- The Cookie is read and displayed here.
**www.ueteribus.com** <--- The login script is hosted here.

Basically those are the only two domains, and I'm trying to get the information from WWW to transfer to Carnal. Which is easier said than done.

Currently I've been trying to use
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.ueteribus.com');

Which hasn't worked, or maybe I have it programmed wrong. Anyways, any help would be very appreciated and if any additional information is required I am more than happy to provide.

NOTE: I do not have access to the **PHP.ini**, the company has denied such access.

```
session_name('LoginSession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'ueteribus.com');
session_start();
```

I've also tried that
That seems to work in creating a named Cookie, but I couldn't figure out how to **call** it. My script wouldn't work anymore to call the actual login status, and I couldn't figure out how to fix it to ensure that this was even working.

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.ueteribus.com'); 
session_start(); 

if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {

echo $_SESSION['error'];    
}
?>
```

Comment: are you putting the same code in all pages? you should have the same session_name, etc. in all the pages you want to have the same session.

Comment: @Mahdi I do not understand what you mean? That code needs to be added to the top of each script? The

session_name('LoginSession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'ueteribus.com');
session_start();

?

Comment: I meant that you have to add your code on the beginning of any php file, where you want to have access to the user session. So you need to have the exact same copy of your `session_name`, etc. in all pages that you're trying to use `$_SESSION`. If you have this code snippet on your `login.php` for example, then you have to have the same session settings on `index.php` in order to access the `$_SESSION`.

Comment: So I should simply add those parameters to the front of every PHP script? Then that should take care of the issue? For example.. Just place the **session_name('LoginSession');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'ueteribus.com');
session_start();** infront of everything?

Comment: what you need to do is to have a global file, let say `globals.inc.php` and write all of your session things there, then you need to include this file in all of your PHP pages that you need session for example there. you can add other things to this file later, like connecting to the database, loading language files, development/debug settings, etc. and then all of those will be available all in your script. just remember that your session initialization should be on top of the page, before any output ...

Comment: @Mahdi I tossed a
    init.php

into my coding and added a single variable in it, I included it via a simple 'include' and a link to the file. But, that only links it to the top of the page? I'm assuming it needs to be stretched across the entire page, and I'm assuming I need more than just session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'ueteribus.com'); and session_start(); in the script?

Comment: @Mahdi What I really need to know is if my method of calling upon the cookie information is correct, because the cookie is created in the browser and I can see it as LoginSession.. But, I can never seem to actually get anything to display from it on the sub domain. Or even named sessions in general, once I've given a session a name.. I cannot seem to call upon it, or get any variables from it.

Comment: Well, I'm a little bit confused by this: ` But, that only links it to the top of the page? I'm assuming it needs to be stretched across the entire page`. Can you post the way you do it? you're probably missing something simple ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
session_name('shared-name-between-sub-domains');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
session_start();
```

Comment: That does create a new cookie on the main domain, but I've been unable to figure out how to access it on the subdomain?

Comment: @user2994429 I'm not really getting your question, however you don't need to do any extra stuff. Just use `$_SESSION` and you must have access it on both main and sub domain, I guess.

Comment: What, I'm saying is.. The Session cookie shows up in my cookies as LoginSession under www.domain.com, but it doesn't show up under domain1.domain.com, and when I try to access it with a simple 'isset' or try to read information from it, it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @user2994429 Well, have no idea what's happening there. Sorry couldn't help, this snippet works fine in all of my projects. Hope you solve it soon somehow, good luck ...

Answer (score 1):

The absolute first two things in your scripts need to be:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.xxxx.com');
session_start();
```

in that order, and any session's begun before adding that code will become inaccessible.

This assumes that both `domain1.xxxx.com` and `www.xxxx.com` live on the same server and use the same instance of PHP. It is impossible to share PHP session data across servers without [writing your own custom session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

If there are no other domains on the server you may want to simply set `session.cookie_domain` in your php.ini.

Comment: I do not have access to the php.ini, and I already talked to the company. They denied me access to the .ini. Also.. I already added that exact same code to my site, and it didn't seem to make any difference?